# Fogbugz / Manuscript integration with Kiwi TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I'm evaluating test case managers, including Kiwi TCMS.

A potential roadblock is the apparent lack of integration with our current bug tracker, Manuscript (Fog Bugz).

Has anyone succesfully integrated with Fogbugz via the respective API's ? Or can someone tell me where to begin down that path?

Comment: If you are willing to hack some code check-in https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#configure-external-bug-trackers and in particular https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.issuetracker.types.html#module-tcms.issuetracker.types and the `tcms/issuetracker` directory.  Pull request would be more than welcome.  FTR we're currently working on enabling testing the bug tracker integration code however that may not be possible with proprietary bug trackers. Still you can develop the code for integration by testing it manually.

Comment: This site is intended to solve specific programming questions. Can you reword you question to fit the site guidelines? Reference this help center link for details on how to ask good questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking